# Get Public key variable from Freighter Wallet

Tags: javascript-sdk, wallets

```
if (window.freighterApi.isConnected()) {
  alert("User has Freighter!");
}

const retrievePublicKey = async () => {
  let publicKey = "";
  let error = "";

  try {
    publicKey = await window.freighterApi.getPublicKey();
  } catch (e) {
    error = e;
  }

  if (error) {
    return error;
  }

  return publicKey;
};

const result = retrievePublicKey();
```

Hi. This is Freighter Wallet javascript code.
I try to find a way to get publicKey outside of this code.
when I console.log(publicKey) after "await" everything ok. But I can't set publicKey to other variables to use outside of this code. When I set a variable after "await" and use it outside it is just undefined.
result log gives me "promise pending". I can use "then" to get results on "console.log" . but still don't know any way to set the result to a variable to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a global variable at the top:

```
var publicKey;
```

(remove the line `let publicKey = "";`)

and set it like you do already:

```
publicKey = await window.freighterApi.getPublicKey();
```

But it will still be available only after the `retrievePublicKey` has run; it's an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) so you have to await it, and that cannot be done from the 'main' method (just `await retrievePublicKey()` won't work). You can do it with `then`, as you already tried, or a self-invoked async function as described [in this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51525281/4751173).